# Sales promotion not removed when required items removed

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

We have an issue with our site where if you add items in a promotion (eg. buy x and y and get z% off y), then remove one of the items (x) you still get the discount (on y). I'm a bit of a self taught noob when it comes to magento and PHP so I don't even know where I would look, does anyone have any ideas?

[image: Conditions]

[image: Actions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out the colleague who set the promotion up put the affected items in both sets of conditions - should have checked there first!

Answer (score 0):

Just check once again all the conditions and actions applied for that promotion.
Discount might be still there because of that reason also.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, not entirely sure I follow, currently this happens - 'buy x and get y for 10% off' customer puts both x and y in basket, removes x, still gets 10% off y.  Please see the edited post with more detail